# React + Rollup - 'r is not defined'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, rollup

**Final edit:** Thanks everyone for your help, however ultimately it was easier for me to transition to Webpack and Storybook. I'm leaving my original question untouched just in case it helps anyone in the future. Also, if anyone stumbles upon any issues configuring these (like I did), the link to the GitHub repo is below.

I'm creating a small lib using React and Rollup and trying to test locally with a CRA-powered project, however I'm facing this issue when importing a component from my library. I don't know if the problem is in my configuration or if this is a bug.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: r is not defined
    at Object.../dist/bundle.js (index.jsx:44)
```

Imported "Message" component where the error is happening

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { string, number, arrayOf } from 'prop-types';

import Container from './Container';

function Message({
  text,
  type,
  timeout,
  classes,
}) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (text && type) {
      setShow(true);
      setTimeout(() => setShow(false), timeout);
    }
  }, [text, type]);

  const date = new Date();

  return (
    <Container
      id={`message-${date}`}
      key={`message-${date}`}
      className={`${type}${classes?.map((className) => ` ${className}`)}`}
    >
      {
        show
          ? (
            <p>{text}</p>
          ) : ''
      }
    </Container>
  );
}

// The source map points to this line when the error happens, but it still happens if I remove it and don't use prop-types, instead pointing to the closing bracket of the 'Message' function
Message.defaultProps = {
  timeout: 3000,
  classes: [],
};

Message.propTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  type: string.isRequired,
  timeout: number,
  classes: arrayOf(string),
};

export default Message;
```

Test component where it's being used:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Message } from 'pure-ui';
import { getRandomArrayElement } from 'formatadores';

const types = [
  'warning',
  'error',
  'success',
];

const texts = [
  'This is a test',
  'I will randomly display a message every so often, so stay sharp',
  'Yet another test message',
];

const timeouts = [
  5000,
  3000,
  1000,
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Running...</h1>
      <Message
        type={getRandomArrayElement(types)}
        text={getRandomArrayElement(texts)}
        timeout={getRandomArrayElement(timeouts)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

rollup config file:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

import React from 'react';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'];

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    watch: true,
    output: {
      file: 'dist/bundle.js',
      format: 'iife',
      sourcemap: true,
      globals: {
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        'prop-types': 'PropTypes',
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      external(),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        presets: [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
        ],
      }),
      resolve({ extensions }),
      commonjs({
        namedExports: {
          react: Object.keys(React),
          'react/jsx-runtime': ['jsx', 'jsxs', 'Fragment'],
          'react/jsx-dev-runtime': ['jsx', 'jsxs', 'jsxDEV'],
          'prop-types': Object.keys(propTypes),
        },
      }),
    ],
    external: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'prop-types',
    ],
  },
];
```

I tried changing the namedExports (and also removing them), linking React from the lib to use the same version from the CRA project (in the lib both React and React DOM are listed as peer dependencies), but I always end with the same result. Is there something wrong with my config? This is the first time I use Rollup for creating a React component lib, so maybe there's something I missed

If the above info is insufficient, [here's the GitHub repo](https://github.com/YoguiSan/pure-ui/tree/develop)

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** I  just saw that I forgot to import React in my test project, however after doing so the results were the same, editing my original question just to fix that.

**Update 1:** I changed several configurations (changed deprecated rollup-plugins to their currently maintained versions, added *globals* to the output part of rollup.config.js, added namedExports to commonjs plugin configuration, added an *external* section specifying react, react-dom and prop-types), but now what I'm getting is a **React is not defined** error, updating the question with the new config

Comment: what does the build/index.js file look like? it looks like the error is happening after youo build/during the build.

Comment: I posted the bundle in JSFiddle because the bundle is 900+ lines, here it is

https://jsfiddle.net/xqza47w8/

Comment: If you just started writing your library, and are willing to switch to TypeScript, you could consider using TSDX instead. It's a zero configuration tool for building React libraries: https://tsdx.io/ - It also uses Rollup under the hood